# Instagram like apis 400 error

Tags: web, instagram

I am the using Instagram API endpoint to like a post, but I keep getting this error:

```
Array ( [meta] => Array ( [error_type] => APINotAllowedError [code] => 400 [error_message] => you cannot like this media ) )
```

This is what [Instagram's developer page](http://instagram.com/developer/limits) says at the bottom:

```
You may also receive responses with an HTTP response code of 400 (Bad Request) if we detect spammy behavior by a person using your app. These errors are unrelated to rate limiting.
```

It's been a 3 or 4 days for me since this error is coming. I can follow and do other endpoint actions easily, but the "like" action is not working at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give steps on how to reproduce the error?

Comment: Did you try from a different IP or PC?

Answer (score 0):

Ran across the same issue. I still continue to receive this error. Is it not because said user has his or her privacy settings set to restrict profile access?